# what packages are required for data flow analysis in LLVM

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

my project is based on data flow and control flow analysis of C programs. I am currently working on elementary OS for llvm. I need to know what additional packages do i need to install (other than clang and compiler-rt) for working on data flow and control flow analysis. I am quite new to LLVM. 
Also, whether those libraries would be enough for generating intermediate representation of the code?

Comment: did, you find any helpful resources?